# How do I change grid color in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I would like to know how to change grid color to be visible in white background.
I have tried changing background color to see grid, but I need a white background.

Comment: You’ve tried [this](https://support.draw.io/questions/1671203/how-to-change-the-background-colour-in-draw.io), right?

Comment: Currently, this doesn't seem possible. you may have to contact draw.io support directly, and see if there are any undocumented features, or if a plugin can be authored to draw a grid for you.

Answer (score 4):

To change the colour of the grid in Draw.io, you have to go to View. Then select Format Panel. To the right, a new panel will show. You have to then select the box to far right, next to the 10pt.